# XmlReader back to object list

Tags: c#, xml

hey i am having hard time to "rebuild"(read) my object. my structure is very simple:

```
groupName<--object  
name<--prop  
addres<--prop  
phone<--prop
```

how can i rebuild it back to the same structure?

here is how i am writing it to xml

```
 public override void Save(PhoneBook pb)
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Group");

        foreach (PhoneBookGroup group in pb.Items)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("GroupName");

            writer.WriteElementString("GroupName", group.GroupName.ToString());
            foreach (Contect contect in group.Items)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Addres", contect.Addres.ToString());
                writer.WriteStartElement("Number", contect.Number.ToString());
                writer.WriteStartElement("Name", contect.Name.ToString());
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you serialize / deserialize PhoneBook object to XML

Answer (score 1):

**Use an `XmlSerializer`**, certainly for a first version since it'll be trivial to code.  If your boss wants it differently *after* seeing how much simpler and less error-prone the serialization version is, you should try to convince him otherwise - part of work isn't just doing what your told, but at least giving honest advice.  Unless this is supposed to be a learning experience, your boss is *wrong* - that's fine and normal, but you should at least *try* to save time and money before doing as he says.  He may just not be aware of the alternatives.

The problems with the manual approach are highlighted by the fact that **your code sample is buggy** - you probably meant `writer.WriteElementString("Number",...` rather than `WriteStartElement("Number",...`.   It's much much safer and simpler to use a more structured approach.

If you *really* need to read raw xml, **I'd recommend using the `XDocument` class** over an `XmlReader` to read your document and linq to xml to extract the relevant bits.  That's *still* simpler than an `XmlReader`, while retaining the full flexibility of hand-written code (it's just a little slower).  If you insist on an `XmlReader` solution (note that there's no technical reason for this), then you should try and write your own first - include your attempt in your question so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: yeah dude tnx for the advice, i think he want me to see this method the hard way, then the easy way.. anyway if u can help me regarding my issue it will be grate  :)

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at your xml output I would seriously look into changing your schema as the output of your Save function creates very strangely structured xml which i think is the reason you are struggling to rebuild it. The current output would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Group>
  <GroupName>
    <GroupName>groupName</GroupName>
     <Addres xmlns="addy">
       <Number xmlns="0123456789">
        <Name xmlns="Henry">
          <Addres xmlns="address2">
            <Number xmlns="9876543210">
              <Name xmlns="Dave" />
              <GroupName>
                <GroupName>secondGroup</GroupName>
                <Addres xmlns="fleet">
                  <Number xmlns="0123456789">
                    <Name xmlns="Me" />
                  </Number>
                </Addres>
              </GroupName>
            </Number>
          </Addres>
        </Name>
      </Number>
    </Addres>
  </GroupName>
</Group>
```

Having said that the resultant xml is not unprocessable and can be read back into the object using the method below. The only thing I have assumed from your Save code is that there is some way of getting from a string to a GroupName object (since you are using the ToString method to get the value into the xml). In my test I implemented the object with an implicit conversion operator as you can see below.

```
class GroupName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

    // Specific conversion from string to GroupName object
    public static implicit operator GroupName(string s)
    {
        return new GroupName() { Name = s };
    }
}

public PhoneBook Rebuild()
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
    {
        // read to the start of the xml
        reader.MoveToContent();

        // create the return object
        PhoneBook returnObject = new PhoneBook();
        returnObject.Items = new List<PhoneBookGroup>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                // read each GroupName Node as a separate node collection
                if (reader.Name == "GroupName")
                {
                    // This is the root node of the groups
                    PhoneBookGroup grp = null;
                    Contact currentContact = null;

                    // loop the reader from this starting node
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {
                            switch (reader.Name)
                            {
                                case "GroupName":
                                    if (grp == null)
                                    {
                                        grp = new PhoneBookGroup();
                                        returnObject.Items.Add(grp);
                                        // must implement an implicit operator between string and GroupName object
                                        grp.Name = (GroupName)reader.ReadElementString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        // start of a new group, so null what we have so far and start again
                                        grp = null;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "Addres":
                                    // Address is the start node for a contact so create a new contact and start filling it
                                    currentContact = new Contact();
                                    if (grp.Items == null)
                                    {
                                        grp.Items = new List<Contact>();
                                    }
                                    grp.Items.Add(currentContact);
                                    // due to the way the xml is being written the value is held as the namespace !!!
                                    currentContact.Address = reader.NamespaceURI;
                                    break;
                                case "Number":
                                    // due to the way the xml is being written the value is held as the namespace !!!
                                    currentContact.Phone = reader.NamespaceURI;
                                    break;
                                case "Name":
                                    // due to the way the xml is being written the value is held as the namespace !!!
                                    currentContact.Name = reader.NamespaceURI;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: Having read Eamon's comment I would definitely agree that the solution I posted is by no means the best solution and will be far more error prone than using a standard approach of the XML Serialiser or any of the other wonderful classes that .NET has to use with XML. IMHO the xmlreader classes should be used as a last resort